# Validate String to time format in C++

Tags: c++

help on efficient way of doing validate string in c++ is accordingly to the time format

```
TimeUserInputstring = "20151432-25:30:20";

TimeFormateAccepted = "yyyymmdd-hh:mm:ss";
```

1) without concatenate string using regular expressions how to check **TimeUserInputstring**  is according to the **TimeFormateAccepted**

2) TimeUserInputstring   is a valid Date Time

Thanks in advance

I have done first part using string concatenation, dont know how to do that in using regular expressions.

and some logic/code to second validation

compiler using is(g++ 11)

Comment: @Pieter21 I m not asked you to do my work, and get lost, without wasting time or even putting comments adding no constructive

Answer (score 0):

Way I m tried to solove

```
 struct tm tm;
        std::string sDateTime = "20150423-15:10:50";
        std::string delimiter = "-";
        std::string sDate = sDateTime.substr(0, sDateTime.find(delimiter)); 
        std::string sTime = sDateTime.substr(9, sDateTime.find(delimiter)); 
        std::string s(sDate);
        if (strptime(s.c_str(), "%Y%m%d", &tm))
            std::cout << "date is valid" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "date is invalid" << std::endl;

    std::cout<<sDate<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<sTime<<std::endl;
```